# How do I update price of multiple products with data coming from a form?

Tags: php, html, pdo, updates

The service implies that user enters a webpage and observes data presented in table view. There are 4 columns, the last column is called **price** in MySQL table, price value for each row (assume that there are 10 rows, i.e. 10 widgets for sale) has been already preloaded in

```
<input type="text" name="something+$row[id]" value="$row[price]"></br>
```

Tag when page is opened, it means that price is visible in textbox, and it can be changed also. The aim is to allow user **update** several/all altered prices in DB table via simple **button click**.

*Please suggest how to populate several rows of MySQL DB table via button click in PHP*.

1. **something+$row[id]** means that name for each textbox should be individual, but I am not sure how to do that.
2. I am incompetent PHP user, so I don't really know which loop better to use here and where to place it.
3. And the last thing, here is my terrible code below, but I hope problem is well-defined.

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
       start loop
           $updated_price = $_POST['something+$row[id]'];
           $update = $conn->query("UPDATE sample SET price = '$updated_price'");
       finish loop
   }
   ```
4. Also please teach me where to use `echo $conn->affected_rows` to see overall DB table changes after loop finished.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing. If you want to include php code in html tag you shall do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row[id]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[price];?>"></br>
```

About the updating, i suggest you do this:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row[id]; ?>"></br>
```

Then in the PHP code:

```
//query the records from the db first
$records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM......"); //or $conn->query(); depending on how you do it

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records))//this also depends on how you deal with the db
    {
            $id = $row['id'];
            if(isset($_POST[$id])) 
            {
               $updated_price = $_POST[$id]+$row['price'];
               $update = $conn->query("UPDATE sample SET price = '$updated_price'" WHERE id = '$id');
            }
    }
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, I will try it tomorrow. The only thing I'm not getting is $updated_price = $_POST[$id]+$row['price']. What does it mean?

Comment: `$_POST[$id]` is the input (price) the user enters in the field that has the name `$id` (which i gave it a value in `$id = $row['id'];` as we gave the html tag that name). `$row['price']` is the original price that we retrieved from the database and we want to update. We updated it by adding the price entered by the user to it(i believe this is what you want to do). I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Understood. Now everything is okay.